# addFooterView() - is it possible to add an entire XML layout using the function?

Tags: java, android

I'm somewhat of a newbie with Android/Java, so I'm going to apologize in advance.

I have two XML files--one for my `activity` which contains a `ListView`, and another one which defines the layout of each item in `ListView`. I also have a .java file for the activity. At this point, I only have `onCreate` and `onStart`. onStart contains the code where I create an `adapter` for my items and then set the `ListView` adapter to that newly created `adapter`.

Anyway, long story short, I was wondering if it was possible to add an entire XML `layout` of `ImageButtons` to the bottom of `ListView` using `addFooterView()`? The way I have it now (after tinkering around with the activity's XML for a while) is using `RelativeLayout` and margins that basically leave the `ImageButtons` fixed at the very bottom of the screen, which is NOT what I want. I wanted the `ImageButtons` to show up at the very bottom of the list, side-by-side.

A link to an example, or posting an example itself would be really nice, as well.

Comment: So you want the _Footer_ to be always visible? I could not really understand the question.

Comment: Sorry. I wanted to know if it was possible to have/pass in an XML file of ImageButtons to addFooterView().

Comment: Could you post an illustration of sorts to help clear things up? If your question however, is simply exploring the possibility of adding a _Footer_ to a `ListView`, then the short answer is yes.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/4e0xTVt.png The three boxes at the bottom are the ImageButtons in another single XML layout that I'd like to have at the bottom of the ListView.

Comment: did you get your answer ?

Comment: @LOL.NO.: Then yes. If this is just it, all the answers posted are correct.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help/answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can add.

```
View footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.completeLayout, youtListView, false);
youtListView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Comment: I hate to ask this...but what exactly is the inflater object in this case? :(

Comment: @LOL.NO.: Check @lynn8570's answer. That explains the `inflater`

Comment: If you want to use any view/layout which is not in the one you set as contentView. You need to use an inflator. Its to inflate existing xml layouts at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

**YES** It is possible.

Create one layout **footerview.xml** having three buttons and you can use it as:

```
RelativeLayout footerview = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(context, R.layout.footerview, null);
listView.addFooterView(footerview);
```

Answer (score 2):

get a inflater

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
          (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

then inflate the xml using

```
View     inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root)
//Inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified xml resource.
```

then add the view return by inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root) to ListView by addFooterView().

I not sure if it is what you want~~~